# PHP regex parse data between [ ]

Tags: php, json, regex

I've a string that I want to convert to a valid JSON and then json_decode it.
Here's what the string looks like:

```
[
    ['test', 'lol'],
    ['test2', 'lol2']
]
[
    ['test32', 'loDl'],
    ['test32', 'loDl2']
]
[
    ['tes23t', 'loDEl'],
    ['testDE2', 'lolDE2']
]
```

I want to get only the data between each

```
[

]
```

so the result might to be:

```
['test', 'lol'],
['test2', 'lol2'],
['test32', 'loDl'],
['test32', 'loDl2'],
['tes23t', 'loDEl'],
['testDE2', 'lolDE2']
```

so I think that I need to use `regex` and `preg_split`, here's what I did:

```
$jsons = preg_split('/\]\s*(?=\[)/', $data, null);
$jsond = "";
foreach ($jsons as $json) {
     $json .= "";
     $jsond .= $json;
} 
return $jsond;
```

but It's not working, I still can't have the data beetween each `[ ]` 
**How can I do that ?**
*Thanks in advance*

**PS: here's the real full string**
https://paste.ee/r/RN7rK

Comment: No, not working, I only get a lot of \n

Comment: since you seems to have a lot of data that comes from an huge file, I suggest to not use a global regex for the whole content, but to work with a stream.

Comment: Well, why not try [`\[([^\][]*)]`](https://regex101.com/r/bD1aY9/1) regex, grab `$matches[1]` and do whatever you please with them?

Comment: While the link you point to is valid JSON, the example you give in your question is not. JSON wraps text in double-quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @trincot when I try to validate the json that i've point in the link, it returns an error using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Indeed, I take back thie first part of my previous comment. The JSON is valid on each separate line, but the line-breaks end a JSON and start a new one. So in total it is indeed not valid. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you [pointed to](https://paste.ee/r/RN7rK) has valid JSON on each line. However, all the lines together do not represent one valid JSON.

I propose to manipulate the data in a minimal way to make the whole text JSON with a simple regular expression. If the original data is in *$data*, then create the JSON as follows:

```php
$json = preg_replace('/(\])\](\R)\[/', '$1,$2', $data);
```

This will remove both the closing bracket at the end of a line, and the opening one at the start of the next line. Instead a comma is inserted. The result will be valid JSON, as the opening bracket right at the start now matches with the very final closing bracket.

I took some representative text from your data:

```php
$data = '[["s","13","shelves_norja","49500","0","1","1","#ffffff,#F7EBBC","Beige Bookcase","For nic naks and books.","","5","true","-1","false","","1","true","0","0","0","false"],["s","117","table_plasto_round*9","45508","0","2","2","#ffffff,#533e10","Round Dining Table","Hip plastic furniture","","-1","false","-1","false","","1","false","0","0","0","false"]]
[["s","118","table_plasto_square*9","45508","0","1","1","#ffffff,#533e10","Occasional Table","Hip plastic furniture","","-1","false","-1","false","","1","false","0","0","0","false"],["s","119","chair_plasto*9","45508","0","1","1","#ffffff,#533e10,#ffffff,#533e10","Chair","Hip plastic furniture","","-1","false","-1","false","","1","false","0","1","0","false"],["s","120","carpet_standard*6","48082","0","3","5","#777777","Floor Rug","Available in a variety of colors","","105","true","-1","false","","1","true","1","0","0","false"],["s","121","chair_plasty*1","45508","0","1","1","#ffffff,#8EB5D1,#ffffff,#8EB5D1","Plastic Pod Chair","Hip plastic furniture","","-1","false","-1","false","","1","false","0","1","0","false"]]';
```

It just has two lines, to limit the data a bit. Now the above code produces this result, pretty printed:

```
[
    [
        "s",
        "13",
        "shelves_norja",
        "49500",
        "0",
        "1",
        "1",
        "#ffffff,#F7EBBC",
        "Beige Bookcase",
        "For nic naks and books.",
        "",
        "5",
        "true",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "",
        "1",
        "true",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "false"
    ],
    [
        "s",
        "117",
        "table_plasto_round*9",
        "45508",
        "0",
        "2",
        "2",
        "#ffffff,#533e10",
        "Round Dining Table",
        "Hip plastic furniture",
        "",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "",
        "1",
        "false",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "false"
    ],
    [
        "s",
        "118",
        "table_plasto_square*9",
        "45508",
        "0",
        "1",
        "1",
        "#ffffff,#533e10",
        "Occasional Table",
        "Hip plastic furniture",
        "",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "",
        "1",
        "false",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "false"
    ],
    [
        "s",
        "119",
        "chair_plasto*9",
        "45508",
        "0",
        "1",
        "1",
        "#ffffff,#533e10,#ffffff,#533e10",
        "Chair",
        "Hip plastic furniture",
        "",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "",
        "1",
        "false",
        "0",
        "1",
        "0",
        "false"
    ],
    [
        "s",
        "120",
        "carpet_standard*6",
        "48082",
        "0",
        "3",
        "5",
        "#777777",
        "Floor Rug",
        "Available in a variety of colors",
        "",
        "105",
        "true",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "",
        "1",
        "true",
        "1",
        "0",
        "0",
        "false"
    ],
    [
        "s",
        "121",
        "chair_plasty*1",
        "45508",
        "0",
        "1",
        "1",
        "#ffffff,#8EB5D1,#ffffff,#8EB5D1",
        "Plastic Pod Chair",
        "Hip plastic furniture",
        "",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "-1",
        "false",
        "",
        "1",
        "false",
        "0",
        "1",
        "0",
        "false"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Not working, call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: I updated my answer. I found the original text has valid JSON on each line, but the line-breaks also represent the end of a JSON string and the start of a new one. I added code in my answer to turn that into one large JSON. Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: No that wasn't this, I need to open and close [ ] for each "data"

Comment: Then the result of the preg_replace must be what you need. I updated my answer including the output of that statement. Can you check?

Comment: Working answer, that was what I'm looking for, thanks

Comment: Great, it was quite an adventure to get that right :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of data and have to preserve memory, you can use something like this:

```
function genArrayFromFHandler($fh) {
    $state = 0; // (1: main brackets, 2: nested brackets, 3: quotes)
    while(!feof($fh)) {
        $c = fgetc($fh);

        switch($c):
            case '[':
                if ($state) $array = [];
                $state++;
                break;

            case ']':
                if ($state == 2) yield $array;
                $state--;
                break;

            case '"':
                if ($state == 2) {
                    $state++;
                    $item = '';
                } else {
                    $state--;
                    $array[] = $item;
                }
                break;

            default:
                if ($state == 3) $item .= $c;                

        endswitch;
    }
}

try {
    $fh = fopen('yourfile.txt', 'r');// or die ('error opening file');
    if (!$fh) throw new Exception('File open failed.');

    foreach (genArrayFromFHandler($fh) as $arr) {
        // do all what you need with the array here
        print_r($arr);
    }

    fclose($fh);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This isn't a fast method but the memory footprint is very low since the file is never fully loaded in memory.

Note I don't know what you want to do with your data and if converting them to JSON is a good idea (JSON is useful to share data between apps, but if you want something you can easily and efficiently querying, it's better to use a database.)

Comment: I get the data with curl, so I have an error "exepted to be ressource, string given"

Comment: @Mrz: If it is a simple url, put it as fopen first parameter (instead of `yourfile.txt`). You can also set options with `stream_context_create`.

Comment: I get this with curl beacause the website block PHP user agent

Comment: @MrZ: you can override the user agent with `stream_context_create` and send another one.

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible solution:

```
$data = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $data);
$data = str_replace("[[", "[", $data);
$jsons = str_replace("]]", "]", $data);
```

echo $jsons

```
['test','lol'],['test2','lol2']['test32','loDl'],['test32','loDl2']['tes23t','loDEl'],['testDE2','lolDE2']
```

Comment: Got an error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $data = "[
      ['test', 'lol'],
      ['test2', 'lol2']
  ]
  [
      ['test32', 'loDl'],
      ['test32', 'loDl2']
  ]
  [
      ['tes23t', 'loDEl'],
      ['testDE2', 'lolDE2']
  ]";

  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $data, $matches);
  $json = '';

  foreach ($matches[0] as &$val) 
  {
      $json .= $val.',';
  } 

  $json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json)-1);

?>
```

will output:

```
['test', 'lol'],['test2', 'lol2'],['test32', 'loDl'],['test32', 'loDl2'],['tes23t', 'loDEl'],['testDE2', 'lolDE2']
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Working but slashes are escaped and json_unescaped_slashes aren't working