# Parsing a string with recursive parentheses

Tags: php, regex, recursion

I'm trying to parse a string with the following structure in PHP:

```
a,b,c(d,e,f(g),h,i(j,k)),l,m,n(o),p
```

For example, a "real" string will be:

```
id,topic,member(name,email,group(id,name)),message(id,title,body)
```

My end result should be an array:

```
[
   id => null,
   topic => null
   member => [
      name => null,
      email => null,
      group => [
         id => null,
         name => null
      ]
   ],
   message => [
      id => null,
      title => null,
      body => null
  ]
]
```

I've tried recursive regex, but got totally lost.
I've got some success with iterating over the string characters, but that seem a bit "over complicated" and I'm sure that is something a regex can handle, I just don't know how.

The purpose is to parse a fields query parameter for a REST API, to allow the client to select the fields he wants from a complex object collection, and I don't want to limit the "depth" of the field selection.

Comment: You do not need a regex for that. You can write a simple parser that will do the job.

Comment: OK, so what do I need? Iterate over the string manually?

Comment: There was an almost identical question, if the answerer does not post the solution soon, I will try to find that code.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried searching, but only got recursive regex examples that gave me an headache :)

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult to find that answer. I can recommend taking a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242041/php-regex-parse-data-between/35242818#35242818) showing how to implement a sample parser in PHP.

Comment: Thank you. Manually parsing the string is not "pretty", but I've managed to solve it manually, for any practical depth (tested it to 20 levels depth, which is an over kill for the purpose I need). I will upload the code later as it is currently all messy. Still hoping for someone to come up with a "clean" solution.

Comment: I do not know if [`\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/aD7uO6/1) will help you much. You will still have to work on further exploding the matches with parentheses.

Comment: This is what I've ended up doing, simply without the regex recursion, because it did not contributed anything to the result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Have a look at my answer - did you have something similar in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Wiktor pointed out, this can be achieved with the help of a lexer. The following answer uses a class originally from Nikita Popopv, which can be found [here](http://nikic.github.io/2011/10/23/Improving-lexing-performance-in-PHP.html).

### What it does

It skims through the string and searches for matches as defined in the `$tokenMap`. These are defined as `T_FIELD`, `T_SEPARATOR`, `T_OPEN` and `T_CLOSE`. The values found are put in an array called `$structure`.
Afterwards we need to loop over this array and build the structure out of it. As there can be multiple nestings, I chose a recursive approach (`generate()`).

### Demo

A [demo can be found on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HY7j5u).

### Code

The actual code with explanations:

```
// this is our $tokenMap
$tokenMap = array(
    '[^,()]+'       => T_FIELD,     # not comma or parentheses
    ','             => T_SEPARATOR, # a comma
    '\('            => T_OPEN,      # an opening parenthesis
    '\)'            => T_CLOSE      # a closing parenthesis
);

// this is your string
$string = "id,topic,member(name,email,group(id,name)),message(id,title,body)";

// a recursive function to actually build the structure
function generate($arr=array(), $idx=0) {
    $output = array();
    $current = null;
    for($i=$idx;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
        list($element, $type) = $arr[$i];
        if ($type == T_OPEN)
            $output[$current] = generate($arr, $i+1);
        elseif ($type == T_CLOSE)
            return $output;
        elseif ($type == T_FIELD) {
            $output[$element] = null;
            $current = $element;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$lex = new Lexer($tokenMap);
$structure = $lex->lex($string);

print_r(generate($structure));
```

Comment: Well, it is something I would consider using, sure. However, I believe there can be even simpler ways.

Comment: Works great! I've done something similar, but without recursion, so that is cleaner than my solution. Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting a lot of " Use of undefined constant T_FIELD" (also with T_SEPARATOR, T_OPEN, T_CLOSE) with PHP 7.0.

Comment: There was a bug in the generate function that ignored last elements and some php notices with undefined constants.
I made a fork with the fixes https://ideone.com/Lfg19Q