# I Want to convert object keys into array keys. For example my keys like data.row.key into ["data"]["row"]["key"]

Tags: php

I Want to convert object keys into array keys. For example my keys like 
`data.row.key` into `["data"]["row"]["key"];`

I want to an array format `["data"]["row"]["key"]`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: read there - http://php.net/en/get-object-vars

Comment: Do you mean you literally have a single array key of `data.row.key`, which you want to expand out?

Comment: Thanks for yor comment 

i have received string "data.row.key" but i need to create a array ["data"]["row"]["key"]

Comment: You mean something like this? [Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426793/parsing-a-string-with-recursive-parentheses

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you exactly want but if your intention is to convert string to array format use the below code.

```
$key = 'data.row.key';
// explode it
$key_array = explode('.',$key);
$array_key_format = '';
foreach($key_array as $key) {
    $array_key_format .= '["'.$key.'"]';
}

echo $array_key_format;
```

Out Put:

```
["data"]["row"]["key"]
```

The out put is only string, cannot be used as array.

Comment: *"make sure we have an array to work with"* -- what makes you think `$key_array` is not an array?

Comment: @axiac. my mistake, explode always returns an array.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder Reddy. I want to use as array. So kindly help me. Now am using this way. like to change another way/simple way

$keys = array_map('strrev', explode(".", strrev($key)));
$setArrKeys = [];
foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
   $setArrKey[0][$value] = $setArrKeys;
   if($key == 0)
       $resultArr[0] = $setArrKey[0];
   else {
       $setValue = $resultArr[0];
        $resultArr = [];
        $resultArr[0][$value] = $setValue;
  }
}